# nano-pi neo available serial port

Tags: nanopi

I have a nano-pi neo H3 board and ubuntu16.01 has been installed on it.

I connected it with computer by serial-USB line.

I can open successfully the /dev/ttyS0  by python and see the code directly

but when i  use the following code to get the available serial port, I got nothing.

```
import serial.tools.list_ports as list_serial

port_list = list(list_serial.comports())

for i in range(0, len(port_list)):
    print(port_list[i][0], port_list[i][1])`
```

Here is my question:

How can I get the available port such as /dev/ttyS0 by Python pyserial library？ Do I need to recompile the kernel?  Thanks